# How to perform a multi-file regex-search with a regexp that encompass several lines?

Tags: regular-expressions, search, newlines

**Scenario**:  I want to detect all `defcustom` sexp that have a `:set` or `:initialize` keyword in all Emacs Lisp files inside a directory tree.

Searching for newline can be problematic depending of the regexp engine and the tool that uses it.   Despite the following, I did not find something that works for several files:

- `[^\0]` when back references and look-around are allowed.  Unfortunately tools like deadgrep do not support them.
- `C-q C-j` is another way but again several tools will not accept multiline regexp.
- I have been able to use `"defcustom [[:ascii:]]+:\(\(type\)\|\(initialize\)\)"` with re-builder to validate that this works inside one file. It won't match text that includes non-ASCII characters, but that's probably OK.  I guess I could write code that iterate across all files and use that expression or something like that.

I would like to find an *Emacs-based* tool that would allow me to write a regexp that support identifying text spread across multiple lines and search for that in all files inside a directory tree without having to write my own.   Does such an *Emacs-based* tool exist?

Comment: Does `project-find-regexp` do the job?

Comment: Did not know that one.  Trying it.  Looks like it needs to have the function to use defined.  A simple search did not work so I don't have it setup correctly for the moment.  Looking into it, thanks...

Comment: What do you mean by "needs to have the function to use defined"?

Comment: Another observation. When people have a problem and they go "I'll use regex" they usually end up with 2 problems. To make sure that you end up with 0 problems, take a look at `M-x re-builder` or https://regex101.com/.

Comment: I saw the `project-fund-function` defvar in project.el.  When I tried to search for "defcustom" into my /usr/local/Cellar/emacs/26.3/share/emacs/26.3/lisp/ it found nothing.  But when I searched into my local Git repo of my code, it found "defcustom"  Then I searched in my local Git repo for "defcustom [[:ascii:]]+:\(\(type\)\|\(initialize\)\)" and it error with "Search failed with status 2: grep: invalid character class"

Comment: I agree with the re-builder.  I use it all the time. I *did use* re-builder.  It's the first word of the second line of the 3rd bullet in my question.

Comment: `project-find-function` is a function. When there's a project under version control, it searches within that dir tree. Otherwise, you need to specify a root dir.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/129678/discussion-between-prouleau-and-aadcg).

Comment: Sorry, I missed that part. I think the issue is that you're using the wrong regex syntax. Eval the following `(setq reb-re-syntax 'string)`. Which is equivalent to doing `M-x re-builder C-c TAB string`.

Comment: This turns out to be a very interesting question. Eager to see what others have to say!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you want to just use a single regexp to search for `defcustom`s that have either `:set` or `:initialize`, with (or without) any of those things possibly being on different lines. Why? Because a single regexp to find either `:set` or `:initialize`, or both, in either order, is complicated.

Instead, you want to use Lisp syntax: find `(defcustom` but search the text between the beginning of that match and the **end of the `defcustom` sexp**. Search it for `:set`, then search it for `:initialize`, without worrying about which might come first or what lines they might be on. No complicated regexp.

IOW, I'd suggest writing a function (command, if you like), that does something like this, in a loop for the file contents (starting from `(point-min)`, with that loop being within a loop over the files you want to search (e.g. `directory-files` or whatever):

1. `search-forward` for `(defcustom`.
2. Go to beginning of the match (`(match-beginning 0)`), and record that position (e.g. in a `let` var).
3. `forward-sexp` to get to the end of the `(defcustom...)` sexp, and record that position.
4. `save-restriction` and `narrow-to-region`.
5. `search-forward` from `(point-min)` for `:set`. If found, accumulate the region bounds as one of your search results, and loop for another search.  If not found, go to step 6.
6. Do step 5, but with `:initialize` in place of `:set`.

If you want to allow for whitespace between the `(` and the `defcustom`, then use `re-search-forward` with an appropriate regexp that allows for it.

Comment: I'd really like to find a way to to a multi-file search of a pattern that spans multiple lines.  I gave that example, but it's not the first time I wanted to do something similar.  My guess is I will have to use PCRE and a backend tool that can support it.  ripgrep and Ag both support PCRE.   I used the regexp I described in my question that worked in re-builder and it's not that complicated.  But re-builder works only on 1 buffer.  I might end up writing a command but for that I'd prefer to use tools like deadgrep, allowing multiple searches, various criteria, etc...

Comment: And yes I could take advantage of the fact that I'm searching inside Lisp code, but I'm looking for a solution that would also work when searching for pattern crossing lines in multiple files written in other languages.

Comment: You're moving the goal post. Your question was about searching within contexts that are `(defcustom...)` sexps. I answered that. If you want to search within *any* kind of context then you can do that with [Isearch+](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/IsearchPlus). You need to define the contexts, and it gives you multiple ways to do that. Then you can search within them, including across multiple buffers/files, and using any kind of isearching - regexp or otherwise. [Icicles Search](https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/Icicles_-_Search_Commands%2c_Overview) offers similar contextual searching.

Comment: You should post a separate question, rather than evolving and widening your question.

Comment: Perhaps., I thought the title and the last paragraph were stating the question, but probably I should not have identified a scenario that strict or added a wider scenario.

Comment: I found that I could use rg.el that supports ripgrep's --multiline option but as you identified the problem is to terminate the search at the end of the S-expr.  So, might as well take advantage of Lisp balanced expression and Emacs ability to do that.    So for the scenario I identified what you propose is the best solution.  Thanks!

Comment: Yes, in general, regexps are limited. They're no substitute for parsing or taking advantage of knowledge of the language (Lisp in this case), including its syntax. And if you try to look for presence of multiple things regardless of order a regexp becomes impractical past 2 things. And regexps can't do negation, for the most part.